# Problems while printing from main a string array created in a function with malloc

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

Why If I printf `myarray[x]` in main function I get no data (a blank line)?
Array is correctly filled (if I print in function I get values)

Here is my code:

```
int main(void)  {
    char thisxpath[300];
    char thisurl[200];
    char** myarray = NULL;
    strcpy (thisurl,"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Pescara&mode=xml&units=metric");
    strcpy (thisxpath,"//city/@name | //country | //weather/@value | //temperature/@value | //precipitation/@value | //humidity/@value | //speed/@*[name()='name' or name()='value']");
    xmlretrive (thisurl, thisxpath, &myarray);

    printf("%s\n", myarray[1]);

    free(myarray);
    return 0;
}

void xmlretrive(char* myurl, char* myxpath, char** myarray) {

    //code that retrieve with cURL the XML and other stuff
    //keyword contain data, that are copied into myarray

    myarray = malloc(20 * sizeof(char*));   
    for (i=0; i < nodeset->nodeNr; i++) {
    keyword = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, nodeset->nodeTab[i]->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
    myarray[i] = malloc((100) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(myarray[i], keyword);
    // if I printf("%s\n", myarray[i]) here I can see that array is actually filled
    xmlFree(keyword);
}
```

Comment: why are you copying from `keyword`? where does that memory live?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing a copy of `myarray` to `xmlretrive`.  If you want to change what `myarray` points to inside `xmlretrive`, you need to pass a pointer to it. i.e. a `char***`

```
void xmlretrive(char* myurl, char* myxpath, char*** myarray) {
    *myarray = malloc(20 * sizeof(char*));   
    for (i=0; i < nodeset->nodeNr; i++) {
        keyword = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, nodeset->nodeTab[i]->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
        (*myarray)[i] = malloc(strlen(keyword)+1);
        if ((*myarray)[i] == NULL) {
            // out of memory.  print error msg then exit
        }
        strcpy((*myarray)[i], keyword);
        xmlFree(keyword);
}
```

Note that I've also suggested some changes to your `malloc` line

- you [shouldn't cast the return from malloc](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html)
- allocate the exact length of string needed for `keyword` to avoid the possibility of buffer overflows for `strlen(keyword)>99`
- `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 so you don't need to multiply the allocation size by it

This will solve your immediate problem but might not be enough to get things working properly.  Some other things to consider:

- `main` needs to call `free` for each allocated member of `myarray` as well as `myarray` itself
- you don't have any way for `main` to know the length of `myarray`.  You could either pass a separate `length` argument into `xmlretrive` or change `xmlretrive` to add a `NULL` element at the end of the array and iterate until you find this in `main`
- `xmlretrive` should probably allocate space for `nodeset->nodeNr + 1` (+1 assumes you add a `NULL` terminator to the array) elements rather than hard-coding a length of 20

Comment: Wow, fast and accurate reply, ty very much simonc. One last question, since I'm allocating 20 rows in my array but rows are not predefined too, is there a way to allocate also the exact number of rows?

Comment: @GiovanniD'Onofrio Yep, you can do `*myarray = malloc((nodeset->nodeNr + 1) * sizeof(*myarray));`  Or remove the `+1` if you don't want to allocate space for a NULL terminator